# Precision of point coordinates in polygon geometry is different from its array

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I was using ArcPy to create new polygons from coordinates but when I create the polygon geometry from my ArcPy Array, the coordinates of the polygon corners are slightly different from that of the points in the array used to create it.

See the code below

```
>>> anc = 0,0
>>> arr = arcpy.Array()
>>> arr.append(arcpy.Point(*anc))
>>> arr
<Array [<Point (0.0, 0.0, #, #)>]>
>>> arr.append(arcpy.Point(45,20))
>>> arr.append(arcpy.Point(25,10))
>>> pg = arcpy.Polygon(arr)
>>> pg
<Polygon object at 0x168f0410[0x168f0b20]>
>>> p = pg.getPart(0)
>>> p
<Array [<Point (4.76837158203e-07, 4.76837158203e-07, #, #)>, <Point (45.0001004934, 20.0001004934, #, #)>, <Point (25.0001004934, 10.0001004934, #, #)>, <Point (4.76837158203e-07, 4.76837158203e-07, #, #)>]>
>>> arr
<Array [<Point (0.0, 0.0, #, #)>, <Point (45.0, 20.0, #, #)>, <Point (25.0, 10.0, #, #)>]>
>>>
```

Anyone has any idea why it's like this or how I can correct this?

Comment: Don't know if this solves the issue but set the spatial reference of the geometry when you create it, it's another parameter on the constructor.

Comment: Thank,  I later added spatial reference to the parameters and the precision increased but not up to what I want.

Comment: `Point` objects use 8-byte float storage. `PointGeometry`, `Polyline`, and `Polygon` use an adaptive compression algorithm based on the parameters of the `SpatialReference`. It ought to be a crime to construct a geometry without a spatial reference, since the default with just four decimal places precision is used if none is provided. You need to read the [Understanding Coordinate Management](https://support.esri.com/en/white-paper/1301) whitepaper. If you're not using a microscope in geodata collection, attempting precision below the 0.1mm default is a fool's errand.

Comment: Adding the spatial reference did give a good result, but along the line in my codes, while doing numerous calculations with the coordinates, my final coordinate differ by about 0.015. This is not actually a big deal, but it's a problem because the bearing of some points to another point is supposed to be 90 degrees but I'm getting something slightly different from 90 degrees.